# PL/SQL Triggers Library Infotainment System

Tags: sql, plsql, triggers

I am trying to make a Library Infotainment System using PL/SQL. Before any of you speculate, yes it is a homework assignment but I've tried hard and asking a question here only after trying hard enough.

Basically, I have few tables, two of which are:
`Issue(Bookid, borrowerid, issuedate, returndate)` and 
`Borrower(borrowerid, name, status)`.

The status in `Borrower` table can be either `'student' or 'faculty'`. I have to implement a restriction using trigger, that per `student`, I can issue only 2 books at any point of time and per `faculty`, 3 books at any point of time.

I am totally new to PL/SQL. It might be easy, and I have an idea of how to do it. This is the best I could do. Please help me in finding design/compiler errors.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trg_maxbooks
AFTER INSERT ON ISSUE
FOR EACH ROW 
DECLARE
    BORROWERCOUNT INTEGER;
    SORF VARCHAR2(20);
BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO BORROWERCOUNT
    FROM ISSUE
    WHERE BORROWER_ID = :NEW.BORROWER_ID;

    SELECT STATUS INTO SORF
    FROM BORROWER
    WHERE BORROWER_ID = :NEW.BORROWER_ID;

    IF ((BORROWERCOUNT=2 AND SORF='STUDENT')
        OR (BORROWERCOUNT=3 AND SORF='FACULTY')) THEN
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
    END IF;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRG_MAXBOOKS
    BEFORE INSERT
    ON ISSUE
    FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF ( :NEW.BORROWERCOUNT > 2
        AND :NEW.SORF = 'STUDENT' )
       OR ( :NEW.BORROWERCOUNT > 3
          AND :NEW.SORF = 'FACULTY' )
    THEN
        RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR (
                             -20001,
                             'Cannot issue beyond the limit, retry as per the limit' );
    END IF;
END;
/
```

**There should not be a commit or rollback inside a trigger. The logical exception is equivalent to ROLLBACK**

Comment: Thanks a lot for your effort. Just one question though - there is no column as 'borrowercount' in any of the tables. I doubt if this would work.

Comment: You should take the count and make it as a parameter for this :) This is not a straight forward answer, but only a model

Answer (score 0):

This is so ugly I can't believe you're being asked to do something like this. Triggers are one of the worst ways to implement business logic. They will often fail utterly when confronted with more than one user. They are also hard to debug because they have hard-to-anticipate side effects.

In your example for instance what happens if two people insert at the same time? (hint: they won't see the each other's modification until they both commit, nice way to generate corrupt data :)

Furthermore, as you are probably aware, you can't reference other rows of a table inside a row level trigger (this will raise a mutating error).

*That being said*, in your case you could use an extra column in `Borrower` to record the number of books being borrowed. You'll have to make sure that the trigger correctly updates this value. This will also take care of the multi-user problem since as you know only one session can update a single row at the same time. So only one person could update a borrower's count at the same time.

This should help you with the insert trigger (you'll also need a delete trigger and to be on the safe side an update trigger in case someone updates `Issue.borrowerid`):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER issue_borrower_trg
   AFTER INSERT ON issue
   FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
   l_total_borrowed NUMBER;
   l_status borrower.status%type;
BEGIN
   SELECT nvl(total_borrowed, 0) + 1, status
     INTO l_total_borrowed, l_status
     FROM borrower 
    WHERE borrower_id = :new.borrower_id
      FOR UPDATE;
   -- business rule
   IF l_status = 'student' and l_total_borrowed >= 3 
      /* OR faculty */ THEN
      raise_application_error(-20001, 'limit reached!');
   END IF;
   UPDATE borrower 
      SET total_borrowed = l_total_borrowed
    WHERE borrower_id = :new.borrower_id;
END;
```

---

Update: the above approach won't even work in your case because you record the issue date/return date in the `issue` table so the number of books borrowed is not a constant over time. In that case I would go with a table-level POST-DML trigger. After each DML verify that every row in the table validates your business rules (it won't scale nicely though, for a solution that scales, see [this post by Tom Kyte](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/ASKTOM.download_file?p_file=6551198119097816936)).

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed explanation!